# Splitting CSV files on specific text

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I have got a system that generates CSV files containing time based data.
Some files have data from two different dates. I want to break up these files into two files, one containing the data from the first day, the other containing the data from the next day. The original file looks like this:

```
09.01.2015 00:00:00,0385 - Veerhaven,VP01 in bedrijf hoog toerental,K,Process message.
09.01.2015 00:00:00,0385 - Veerhaven,VP01 in bedrijf laag toerental,G,Process message.
08.01.2015 23:59:55,1475 - Schaatsbaan,PO01 in bedrijf,G,Process message.
08.01.2015 23:59:52,0311 - Abraham van Stolkweg,PO01 in bedrijf,G,Process message.
```

The first 10 Characters are the date of the event. I want to break up the file in two output files seperating the data from the two days. I have to do this using batch processing because it has to be done every day over a lot of files.

I hope someone can help me on my way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "file=c:\somewhere\data.txt"

    for %%f in ("%file%") do for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%%~ff") do (
        if not defined %%a (
            findstr /b /c:"%%a" "%%~ff" > "%%~dpnf.%%a%%~xf"
            set "%%a=1"
        )
    )
```

The first `for` command is used only to retrieve a reference to the file and being able to separate path, filename and extension (that will be used later to generate the output files).

Second `for` loop reads the input file and for each line retrieves the first token/field in the line using spaces as delimiters (the default behaviour in `for /f` command). This value is used to filter the input file and declare environment variables:

- If the variable is not defined, it is the first time the value is seen, matching records are extracted from the input file to a new output file and the variable is defined.
- If the variable is defined, this value has been seen and the corresponding output file generated,  the extraction is skipped and the process continues reading the next line.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "files=c:\somewhere\*.txt"
    set "outputFolder=c:\where\to\put\files"

    for %%f in ("%files%") do (
        setlocal
        for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("%%~ff") do if not defined %%a (
            findstr /b /c:"%%a" "%%~ff" > "%outputFolder%\%%~nf.%%a%%~xf"
            set "%%a=1"
        )
        endlocal
    )
```

The wildcard management in the input needs no changes: `for %%f` iterates over the indicated set, being it only a file or a set of files.

The output folder is stored in a environment variable. The redirection is changed to use the variable insted of the path of the input file.

As the variables used to determine if the indicated token has been processed needs to be deleted for each file processed, the loop that processes the file contents is wrapped in a pair of `setlocal/endlocal` that cleans the flag variables after each file has been processed

Comment: Is it also possible to modify this to use it with wildcards and a input and out directory?   have been trying to modify it but haven't yet figured it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks MC ND. I haven't quite got it to work. It works fine with just one file. It is split and te resulting files are redirected to the output directory. But with multiple files it is not working. I even made copies of of the text file e.g. tst1.txt tst2.txt tst3.txt and so on. Switching off echo off to se what happens, They are all processed but in the output directory I found only tst1.txt splitted. Hope you can help me out, regards Cornelis

Comment: @Cornelis, blind, i was blind. Sorry, my fault. I forget to clean the variables. Please try the updated code.

Comment: I have tried it, the problem is solved! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

read `HELP FOR` to learn how to use the `FOR` command to loop over the lines of a file and parse its contents. Then, try

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (timedata.txt) do (
  echo %%a ... %%b
)
```

you see that you may use `%%a` to split the files by date, so you could figure out something like

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (timedata.txt) do (
  echo %%b >>timedata.%%a.txt
)
```

or more generically

```
set fn=%~dpn1
set fx=%~x1
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in (%~1) do (
  echo %%b >>%fn%.%%a%fx%
)
```